# Logging doesnt work inside controller - Serilog ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: logging, asp.net-core-webapi, serilog

I have a ASP .NET Core 3.1 web API and I'm trying to use Serilog, but for some reason any logs I create inside of my controllers don't log anything. Logging works when I log from the Startup class or through Middleware like UseSerilogRequestLogging().

My Program class:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static IConfiguration _configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Development"}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(_configuration)
                .Enrich.WithMachineName()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("Application Starting.");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "The Application failed to start.");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

My controller:

```
        private readonly IJobServiceRepository _jobServiceRepository;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for this API controller
        /// </summary>
        public JobsController(IJobServiceRepository jobServiceRepository, ILogger<JobsController> logger)
        {
            _jobServiceRepository = jobServiceRepository ??
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(jobServiceRepository));
            _logger = logger ??
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
            _logger.LogInformation("TEST");
        }
```

My appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Try LogError to see if that works, just to give you an idea of a direction to look

Comment: I copied your configuration from `Program.cs` and configuration and it works. Are you sure that your controller is invoked and given action is triggered? Maybe you have something wrong with routing and you don't see logs from controller, because controller is not invoked?

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks good in `Program.cs` class.

In `Program.cs` you configure Serilog and use it `Log.Information("Application Starting.");` - as a result it works

You can also use it in `JobsController` `Log.Information("Message");`

Comment: Field can be `ILogger`, you don't need to use generic declaration.

Comment: @Hostel thanks for you comment, I agree with you - I updated my answear.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your controller class, where you are creating a logger instance in the second line, i.e

```
private readonly ILogger _logger
```

replace `ILogger` with `ILogger<"Your controller name">`, which is `JobsController` in your case.